# Alamofire 5 responseDecodable failure

Tags: swift, alamofire

Alamofire has a nifty `.responseDecodable` function that makes parsing simple when `request.result =  .success` but, how to decode an error object in case of `failure`?

In my case, backend can return a myriad of errors since, for instance, a credit card charge may have an infinitude of reasons - OTP failed, declined etc.

Should i change my approach towards requests? Since Alamofire doesn't really support error handling (at least with `responseDecodable`) as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on how your responses are structured. There are a few ways to approach this:

- Create an `enum` representing your responses, generic to the success (and perhaps failure) value. Something like `APIResponse<Success>`, which is itself `Decodable` and will try to parse the success value or an error from the response. This would allow you to keep using `responseDecodable` but you'll have to rectify response errors with request errors produced by Alamofire yourself.
- Create your own `ResponseSerializer` that knows how to decode success and failure values, which can you hook into Alamofire's `response` method.
- Relatedly, you can extend `DataRequest` with a custom `response` method that uses your custom serializer.

Comment: This seems plausible and and reasonable. I think I’m bound to follow with a new responseseerializer. Thanks!